# When to use PInoke? - PInvoke CopyFile versus File.Copy

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

What advantages and disadvantages have each side?

As far as I am concerned PInvoke is faster and also has no problems with long paths? So if I have to copy large file structures e.g. terabytes of data and thousands of folders / files, I should use PInvoke?

e.g. if you want to copy large file-structures from/to shares and retain permissions.

Comment: `CopyFile` won't be any faster than `File.Copy`. Ultimately `File.Copy` will call a Win32 API function to do the work, and that's where the time will be spent. Anyway, this question doesn't really fit here. You need to ask something more specific.

Comment: File.Copy() already pinvokes CopyFile().  So no need to help.  Consider to get familiar with the Reference Source, it helps you answer these kind of questions yourself.  https://referencesource.microsoft.com/  Just type in "file.copy" in the search box.  You'll instantly see the big advantage, getting good exceptions is very important.

Comment: Accessing the disk is *many* orders of magnitude slower than a function call. Copying files is slow. Trying to improve function call performance doesn't help to make that slow operation any faster. Please read [Teach Yourself Programming in Ten Years](http://norvig.com/21-days.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to use PInvoke here, since `File.Copy` itself [calls the Windows `CopyFile` function already](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,168).

The file path length is already resolved since .NET 4.6.2. See [this blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jeremykuhne/2016/06/21/more-on-new-net-path-handling/) where it describes the app switch you need to set in your `app.config`.

The only thing the .NET Framework does is some additional checks and error handling, as you can see in the referenced source code. Nothing less, nothing more.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the useful link. Can it be that File.Copy is slower when copying huge amounts of data because of the additional exception handling / checks?

Comment: No. Never... As the answer said File.Copy calls CopyFile. So there is no difference.

Comment: But for example if I check for permissions first for the folder only and then use pinvoke to just copy everything in this folder instead of using file.copy which checks permission for each file?

Comment: Don't be foolish. You won't be able to test for permissions properly. You'll only get it wrong. And then your program won't work. And the net result will be a program that has identical performance, but sometimes doesn't work. You are trying to solve a problem that does not exist. Let the system do its job. It knows how to do it. It does it correctly.

Comment: I already have a method written by a competent programmer here, that uses PInvoke. And I wanted to compare the File.Copy to his implementation. He does his own error handling and he says it's a lot faster.

Comment: If he is competent, and concludes that doing the same thing two different ways exhibits significantly different runtime characteristics, then it is your duty to question their competency. There is none.

Comment: Well that's why I started this thread. I thought since we call the copy method for millions of files and folders, adding only 100ms to each call because of error handling / exception checks means a lot of additional time.

Comment: @Thypari: Error handling adds *nanoseconds*, not microseconds, or milliseconds. I posted the link in a comment to your question, so that you get a feeling for how slow disk access is, compared to executing instructions on the CPU.